# Running background tasks ending with a local notification in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification

This is in response of an effort in order to implement an app in a way, so that I could run some code at specific interval of time i-e Morning 9:00 am daily.

Lets take an example of an Alarm.

If user is allowed to set a time interval, during which he is going to remain busy, so now after setting two - three intervals for his daily schedule.

After the app is suspended or in foreground, user needs a reminder before entering to and after getting out of the interval.

I need guidance for this problem in a way :

1. Local notifications for this situation in swift
2. Changing the mode of device from ringer to silent during that interval
   OR
   Accessing programatically 'Do not Disturb Me' feature of IOS

Your kind conveyance regarding this issue will be really productive for me.

Thanks.